# How to write Insert and Update query in one single Query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have below mentioned Issue.

I am developing inventory system using php.

According to that i have to add invoiced items to table.

Dynamically generated text box used to collect received item details.

I have current_stock table and it contain Item-name and qty columns.

Item-name is primary key field.

item which i am going to insert if already exist quantity  should be updated with new value.

if it is not exist should be inserted as a new row.

This is must be done in loop because i use dynamically genarated text box and data collect using $item[] and $qty[] arrays.

I am try to use several ways to solve this issue unable to execute in for loop but not yet success.

please help me.........

Comment: check this: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/02/21/flexible-insert-and-update-in-mysql/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show your code for proving how far did you try and help others members to understand your problem better while you will be providing a context of your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
INSERT INTO table (id, item_name, qty) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
item_name="A"
```

If you specify [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row.

Comment: main issue is unable to execute ON DUPLICATE KET UPDATE in for that is my issue....

if (is_array($qty) && ($item)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($qty); $i++) {
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO received_items (po_id,invoice_number,item_name,qty)VALUES($id,'$invoice',$item[$i]',$qty[$i])";
            $query3="INSERT INTO current_stock (item-name,Qty) VALUES('$item[$i]',$qty[$i]) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item-name='$item[$i]',qty=qty+$qty[$i]";
            $result_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            $result_2 =  mysqli_query($conn, $query3);

Comment: why you cant execute  on Duplicate key update ,is there any error

Comment: your Item-name is primary key field so make it unique also.it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple query excution you have to use

```
mysqli_multi_query()
```

like this :

```
mysqli_multi_query("INSERT INTO TABLE SET Field='Value',FieldB='ValueB';
UPDATE TABLE SET Field='Value',FieldB='ValueB' WHERE FIELDID='VALUEID';")
```

i hope this will work.have fun.

Comment: yes but you have to use connection string with it like

Comment: mysqli_multi_query($con,"INSERT INTO TABLE SET Field='Value',FieldB='ValueB';
UPDATE TABLE SET Field='Value',FieldB='ValueB' WHERE FIELDID='VALUEID';")

Comment: no my requirement is if item already exist in database it should be updated otherwise should be inserted. However query should be executed in loop because data collected by arrays....

Comment: yes query execute in loop so not possible in single query. need to use TRANSACTION mysql